# US Playstation2 in Europe

Tags: display, europe, pal, playstation

I just moved from the States to Germany and I brought my Playstion 2 with me (purchased in the US). I understand that I need an adapter and a converter in order to prevent it from blowing up when plugging it in, but will the device even play on my TV?

I've purchased a Sony Bravia LCD last week (new, from a store).

Comment: Question such as yours appear to be outside this site's scope according to the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an 220V (or was it 230V? anyway it's not that important) 50Hz to 110V 60Hz adapter.

If you do connect you PS2 to the TV, there's a chance you'll  get black and white picture. Most likely your PS2 is set to use NTSC standard for transmitting TV signal while in Europe PAL and SECAM are used. You should read PS2's and TV's manuals first. It is possible that TV does support NTSC or that PS2 does support PAL. If they don't, you'll need an adapter to convert NTSC to PAL. After taking a look at their prices, it may be cheaper to buy a PS2 in Europe instead of the adapter.